# wireless router on LAN

Tags: wifi, wireless-bridge

Can I put a wireless router (for a laptop to talk to) which is configured to use DHCP on our work LAN?

I just need the laptop to be able to talk to the internet. Will it automatically get the gateway information when it is assigned an IP via DHCP?

Comment: A side note here. Before plugging it in, see if it's OK with your IT staff/internal policies. Technically this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Checking with the IT department is absolutely essential, as it is *very likely* to be a problem! At many companies, setting up an unauthorized or "rogue" access point would be an automatic firing offense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. This is the usual work of a DHCP server.
Your wireless router receives from DHCP server all information it needs to connect to your LAN; then you must configure the router to connect laptops via wireless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your admin for an IP to use for the wired interface of the router and also for granting external access to this IP. That being said that should work without any problem.